# buscar y reemplazar pandas python, filtro con dos valores

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo dos columnas:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csv =StringIO(u'''\
debit,move_id/id,
2002,32
2000,33
2001,34
2002,6166
2002,6166
2003,6541
2004,6166
2002,8089
''')
```

y quiero filtrar y cambiar los valores en debit cuando en debit y move_id/id coincidan, ejemplo:

> df.debit[(df["move_id/id"] == 6166) & (df.debit == 2002)]

y quedaria:

```
     debit   move_id/id
0    2002      32
1    2000      33
2    2001      34
3    2010      6166
4    2010      6166
5    2003      6541
6    2004      6166
7    2002      8089
```

**alguna idea??**

Comment: Hola Yan.  Las preguntas que piden ideas son muy amplias. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: La pregunta debe concretarse un poco más. El ejemplo que pones tiene una traducción directa: `df.debit[(df["move_id/id"] == 6166) & (df.debit == 2002)] = 2010`, pero seguramente no es eso lo que querías preguntar. Dices que "cuando los valores coincidan" ¿en filas contiguas además, o en general en toda la tabla? ¿qué valor asignar cuando coincidan? ¿Siempre 2010?

Comment: Los valores "6166" y "2002" son fijos definidos por el usuario y el filtro `df.debit[(df["move_id/id"] == 6166) & (df.debit == 2002)]` esta hecho, lo que no se hacer es reemplazar el valor original por el que quiero sin afectar todas las demas lineas y columnas.

Comment: @YanChirino Está en mi anterior comentario, fíjate que hay una asignación `= 2010`, que es el valor asignado. Ya que a la izquierda de la asignación está el filtro, se asignarán sólo las filas seleccionadas (y sólo la columna `debit` ya que lo que asignamos es `df.debit[ ... filtro ...]`)

Comment: @YanChirino, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar el método `loc` o `iloc` para seleccionar las filas o celdas que necesitas y luego modificarlas

Por ejemplo para seleccionar las celdas de la columna "debit" cuando "move_id/id" sea 6166 y "debit" sea 2002 puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
df['debit'].loc[(df["move_id/id"] == 6166) & (df['debit'] == 2002)]
```

Luego solo asignas un nuevo valor

```
df['debit'].loc[(df["move_id/id"] == 6166) & (df['debit'] == 2002)] = 2022
```

El resultado del `dataframe` sería:

```
    debit   move_id/id
0   2002    32
1   2000    33
2   2001    34
3   2022    6166
4   2022    6166
5   2003    6541
6   2004    6166
7   2002    8089
```

Nota que solo se actualizó el valor de "debit" para las celdas que seleccionamos anteriormente